# An abelian group has different module structures

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with the identity element. Let $$P=X^{n}+a_1X^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n\in A[X]$$ be a monic polynomial. The class map $\pi$ is $$\pi: A[X]\rightarrow A[X]/(P), X\mapsto \overline{X}:=X+(P).$$ It is easy to check that the $A$-algebra $B=A[X]/(P)$ is a free $A$-module of rank $n$, because $\overline{ X^{0} }, \cdots , \overline{ X^{n-1} } $ is a basis for this $A$-module.

If we consider the dual basis  $\overline{ X^{0} } ^{ \vee }, \cdots , \overline{ X^{n-1} } ^{ \vee } $ of $B^{ \vee }=\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,A)$, then $B^{ \vee }$ is a free $A$-module of rank $n$. But $B^{ \vee }$ is also a $B$-module. We can define the operation by
$$\mu:B\times B^{ \vee }\rightarrow B^{ \vee }, (b,f(x))\mapsto bf(x):=f(bx)$$for all $b,x\in B$ and $f\in B^{ \vee }$.

> Is the $B$-module $B^{ \vee }$ a free module of rank $n$?

If we consider $f\in B^{ \vee }=\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,A)$, then $f:A[X]/(P)\rightarrow A$. I also want to know

> how to define the action of $f$? I mean $c_{0}+c_{1}u+\cdots +c_{n-1}u^{n-1}\mapsto ?\in A$.

The elements in $A[X]/(P)$ have the form $c_{0}+c_{1}u+\cdots +c_{n-1}u^{n-1}$, where $u=X+(P), c_i\in A (i=0,1,\dots ,n-1)$. Could anyone help me with these, please?

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what your last sentence is; it's quite hard to interpret what is meant by "Does this B-module is a free module of rank n?" - are you asking whether the B-module is a free module of rank n?

Comment: @Andrew D: I am sorry. My English is poor.

Comment: What do you mean by «the action of $f$»?

Comment: I mean $c_{0}+c_{1}u+\cdots +c_{n-1}u^{n-1}\mapsto ?$